# Inserting values into specific indices in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, insert, concatenation

I have two lists:

```
l1 = [254, 255, 254, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 254]
l2 = [(255, 255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255, 0)]
```

I want to modify l1 and insert 0s from l2 into indexes 3, 7 and 11 so l1 would look like this:

```
[254, 255, 254, 0, 254, 254, 254, 0, 255, 255, 254, 0]
```

It works when I use this code:

```
l1.insert(3, l2[0][-1])
l1.insert(7, l2[1][-1])
l1.insert(11, l2[2][-1])
```

But when I try doing it without insert() function:

```
l1 = l1[:3] + l2[0][-1] + l1[3:]
l1 = l1[:7] + l2[1][-1] + l1[7:]
l1 = l1[:11] + l2[2][-1] + l1[11:]
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the problem is that you use `+` to **concatenate lists**, but here you do not concatenate lists, you concatenate a list with an `int` with a list. Indeed:

```
l1 = l1[:3] + l2[0][-1] + l1[3:]
#    ^ list   ^ int       ^ list
```

You can solve the issue by making the second argument a list (for instance by surrounding it with square brackets):

```
l1 = l1[:3] + [l2[0][-1]] + l1[3:]
#    ^ list   ^ list        ^ list
```

Nevertheless it is **better to use `insert`**: it is less error-prone (we can assume that it is tested effectively) and furthermore usually more efficiently (since the insertion is done inplace).

Finally note that if you insert `0`, it does *not* matter where that `0` originates from: `int`s are *immutable*, and usually small `int`s, are singletons: there is at all time only one zero `0` `int` in Python.